# .e00 files - can they be converted to CSV files and used in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, csv, e00

I am having trouble opening an .e00 file in QGIS. (QGIS keeps locking up, and I have to "force-quit".) The file is political administrative boundaries in China.

Would it be feasible to convert the .e00 file to a CSV and import that CSV? 'Cause the .e00 file, when I open it with a text editor, looks like a spreadsheet document.

I am using QGIS 2.12 Lyon on a Mac running OS X 10.10.5.

Edit: I do not see how my question is a duplicate of "How to read Arc/Info e00 vector files (no binaries) with Python?" [I'll call that "Question A".]
 First, Question A says "I can easily read e00 files with QGIS..." but in my case, I cannot *easily* read e00 files. I have only partial success displaying their data. 
Second, I am asking whether I can turn my e00 file into a CSV file and then use the CSV file in QGIS. Question A makes no mention of CSV files.
Third, I do not mention Python. I have no idea how to use Python. 
I have read Question A and the answers given, and I do not understand what they are talking about. For example, when I run "ogrinfo --formats" I get "-bash: ogrinfo: command not found".

Comment: `.e00` is an entire ***family*** of formats, only some of which are human-readable.  Please edit the question to specify what type of data is present in the file.

Comment: Do you have `ogrinfo`? Run that on the file to see what's inside. Paste the result here.

Comment: @EvanCarroll - I searched for an hour for how to run "ogrinfo" on my Mac, to no avail. But here is a portion of what the file shows when opened with the Mac text editor: 
EXP  0 /TMP/CHINA_REDO/PBD90.E00                                                
ARC  3
         1     20000         1         2         2         4       115
 1.01033782495655E+06 4.11655966853031E+06
 1.01119242149622E+06 4.11713380553799E+06
 1.01194598841895E+06 4.11787328699297E+06
 1.01270651517084E+06 4.11860145278805E+06
 1.01352504893309E+06 4.11923530770502E+06
 1.01442843040187E+06 4.11971385454976E+06